Debugging node.js running in an Alpine Docker container
I created a simple node server with a handful of routes. It works perfectly running in my local Ubuntu environment.  I can connect with my browser and get result sets back.
I containerized it using Alpine as the base and now my web client is no longer getting results from the endpoints.
docker run --name node-test -d rf-server-test-image -p 3000:3000

Running docker logs is not showing anything helpful - even with hapi request.log() enabled.  The output is:
Server running on http://localhost:3000

Which is what I would expect to see.  Can anyone share tricks on how to get meaningful debug/trace information from the running container?  I can attach to /bin/sh but I am not seeing any log information persisted.
From the shell context I ran "node app.js" and I get the exception that the address is already in use - which tells me that node is running.  It is just not accepting input from my browser.
The container host is Linux and I can verify the container is bound to the bridge network.  In the container, I can see that the node process is bound correctly.
src # ps aux | grep node
    1 root      0:00 node app.js -p 172.0.0.1:3000:3000

I also changed the host property in my hapi server init() stanza from localhost to "0.0.0.0".  That has not helped either.
const init = async () => {
  const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
    host: "0.0.0.0",
  });


In my experiences, chances are you are not forwarding port 3000 or not forwarding it to local port 3000. See Docker documentation on port forwarding.

docker run --name node-test -d rf-server-test-image -p 3000:3000

Problem solved.  I had a typo in the way that the host value was being passed into the Hapi server constructor.

If you are running node container locally then I would recommend to just run it with --inspect-brk and publish 9229 port from your container. Then you can use Chrome devtools to connect to that port.
See this guide for details.
